# WSO2 ESB Custom Message Processor - access the Message

Tags: wso2-esb

I am using the WSO2 ESB Message processor with the "replay sequence" which handles outputs from the invoked WS.

I am facing now a situation where I need to compile a message which should contain also some information from the end point request. 
My question is: how can I access the request message, once the message is carried out by the Message processor in the "replay sequence", possibly also in the Fault sequence in order to show inputs caused the error?

Answer (score 0):

Before you store the message into the JMS queue using the store mediator, use property mediator to set the properties in default/synapse scope. For an example instance,

```
<property expression="//xpath/to/payload"
        name="FileName" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Then in the replySequence access the necessary properties and do the validation there. Also make sure only to copy necessary properties, not the whole payload.